# javascript positioning is not changing contionously

Tags: javascript

```
function main() {
  var abc = document.getElementById('space');

  abc.style.left += 10 + 'px';

  main2();
}

function main2() {
  setInterval(main(), 1000);
}
```

according to this code value position of space must change in 1 second. but it is not working position is changing only once

Comment: element is positioned absolute in css?  next thing setInterval(main,1000) ; - use declaration not function result.

Comment: You call `main` immediately and pass the result of the `main` function to the `setInterval` . Check the duplicate for more details.

Comment: maciej sikora yes positioning is absolute

Comment: An additional note: On the on hand your code creates a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`  error, that you should have mentioned with your question. And either use `setInterval` or and remove the `main2()`, because this will create an additional interval with each iteration, or stay with the `main2()` and use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are executing the `main` function, instead of just passing it. Basically it's like this:

```
setInterval(function() { /* something inside */ }, 1000);
```

I can take this function and declare it outside:

```
function main() {
    // something inside
}
setInterval(main, 1000); // here I just pass the `main` function
```

What you are doing is not passing, but executing the function:

```
function main() {
    // something inside
}
setInterval(main(), 1000);
```

Comment: is there any diffrence in between setInterval(main,1000) and setInterval(main(),1000)

Comment: `setInterval(main(),1000)` - `main` will be executed only once. `setInterval(main,1000)` - `main` will be executed every one second.